# ajax validation not working in form submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `ajax` validation in `URL` field, I getting correct message (after a check from database), but still form is submitting

I want if I getting an invalid message then the form should not submit, how can I do this ?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Url").blur(function() {
            var element = $(this).val();
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('Welcome/check_user_status'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: "url="+element,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    $('#emailInfo').html(data);

                    if(jQuery.trim(data) === "Emailvalid")
                    {
                        alert("Emailvalid");

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        alert("Email Invalid");
                    }
                    console.log(data);
                }

            });
        });
        // return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: in else condition put `return false;`

Comment: i did  but still not working

Comment: what error you are getting in console

Comment: use this event.preventDefault();

Comment: data: 'url': 'element',

Comment: Can you share html as well;

Comment: please post your actual `html` that is coming on browser. and put it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm"> 


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Url").blur(function() {
            var element = $(this).val();
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('Welcome/check_user_status'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: "url="+element,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    $('#emailInfo').html(data);

                    if(jQuery.trim(data) === "Emailvalid")
                    {
                        alert("Emailvalid");

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        alert("Email Invalid");

                    $("form").submit(function(e){
                       e.preventDefault();
                     }); 
                    }
                    console.log(data);
                }

            });
        });
        // return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tests are placed in the success callback, which is fired *after* the `$.ajax()` call has successfully POSTed data and received a response.  No matter what you put in there, it is only ever going to happen *after* the form has been submitted.

If you are trying to do validation *before* your POST, you need to add that separately.  Depending on what kind of validation you need, you could write your own simple tests, or use a plugin - [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) is a great option.

Comment: i done this , 

in else part, i  put just one line and its working 


" jQuery('#Url').val(''); "

Answer (score 0):

add this in your footer file

```
<script>
var burl="<?php echo base_url('') ?>";
var surl="<?php echo site_url('') ?>";
</script>
```

and then use this surl on ajax url...
like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Url").blur(function(e) { // add e
            e.preventDefault();// prevent other events
            var element = $(this).val();
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: surl+"Welcome/check_user_status",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {"url":element}, // check the change
                success: function(data){
                    if($.trim(data) === "Emailvalid"){ // instead of jQuery use $
                        alert("Emailvalid");
                        $('#emailInfo').html(data); // put here 

                    }else{ // remove the space between if and else
                        alert("Email Invalid");
                        return false; // add here 
                    }
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```